# Can't delete cookie in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, logout

I've got a logout.aspx that is called when the user clicks logout and there is where I want to delete the cookies but it just won't do it...

```
public partial class LogoutUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;

        cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Basket");
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Basket");
        }

        foreach (string item in cookie.Values.AllKeys)
        {
            Response.Cookies[item].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);                
        }

        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies["Basket"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);    
        Session.Abandon();   

        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

The cookie stores the values in the basket but after logging out I can still access the basket I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is some relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx).

I believe your mistake is in this line:

```
if (cookie == null)
```

You're checking for null, rather than checking for not null. Thus,

```
HttpCookie cookie;

    cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Basket");
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("Basket");
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

should do the trick.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this ?

Session identifiers for abandoned or expired sessions are recycled by default. That is, if a request is made that includes the session identifier for an expired or abandoned session, a new session is started using the same session identifier. You can disable this by setting **regenerateExpiredSessionId** attribute of the sessionState configuration element to **true**. For more information, see Session Identifiers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx